# Name for distros based on other distros

Tags: ubuntu, distribution-choice, elementary-os, distributions

I'd like to know if there is any way to call the distros that are based on other distros, i.e., is there any noun that defines Elementary Os (which is based in Ubuntu) appart from distribution? Thanks!!

Comment: Respin? or just spin? or fork? or any of those kind of terms would do. AFAIK they are just called Ubuntu based distributions mostly.

Comment: Fork, Or spin. For ubuntu in particular people often use "flavor"

Comment: Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, are you only looking for spin-offs of non-spin-off distributions? Or do you assume a first derivative to have the same name as a second derivative?

Answer (score 4):

They're generally known as [derived distributions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Derived_distributions) or [derivatives](https://wiki.debian.org/Derivatives). This includes [Ubuntu derivatives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives) such as elementary OS.